# How to retrieve data from firestore when the barcode reader scans the barcode

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, barcode-scanner

Based on : https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner

I would like to **retrieve the data from firestore class when the barcode reader scans the barcode** but I don't know how to do it. And also i want to proceed to the other page after scanned the barcode. Please help me to solve to it. Here is my code :

```
    private fun codeScanner() {
    codeScanner = CodeScanner(this, scanner_view)

    codeScanner.apply {
        camera = CodeScanner.CAMERA_BACK 
        formats = CodeScanner.ONE_DIMENSIONAL_FORMATS 
        autoFocusMode = AutoFocusMode.SAFE 
        isAutoFocusEnabled = true 
        isFlashEnabled = false 

        decodeCallback = DecodeCallback {
            runOnUiThread {
                tv_textView.text=it.text
            }
        }

        errorCallback = ErrorCallback {
            runOnUiThread {
                Log.e("Scan", "Camera initialization error: ${it.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    scanner_view.setOnClickListener {
        codeScanner.startPreview()
    }
}
```

Here's how my data in firestore looks like:
[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al60A.png)